# Why does my controller keep routing my link_to toward "show" action? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

So I am pretty stumped. I am new to Ruby on Rails (I am using Rails 4) and I have been trying to figure out for the last two days why my `link_to` tag keeps routing my `login` action to `show` instead. I removed the `show` action from my controller and even deleted `show.html.erb` and yet Rails remains persistent in trying to route it to a `show` action that no longer exists.

I removed all my `redirect_to` functions, and the `link_to` I create takes me to the correct page `localhost:8000/users/login` but now displays the error `Unknown Action: The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController`.

I have read up other SO questions that were similar, and some suggest that it may be an issue with `jquery_ujs`, which I removed from my file to see if it was the problem, but I still ended up with the same result.

The files in my `views` directory are as follows:

- views

  - users

    - new.html.erb
    - login.html.erb

Here's what my code looks like:

The `link_to` in **users/new**  (**new.html.erb**)

```
<li><%= link_to "Login", users_login_path %></li>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users

root 'users#new'
get 'users/create'
get 'users/login'
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new

end

def create
    @user = User.create(:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password])
    @user.save
    @users = User.all
end

def login
    @message = "Success"

end


end #end class
```

**login.html.erb** (Just testing an output here to see if it ever gets to this page)

```
<h3><%= @message %></h3>
```

Output of **rake routes** command

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
       users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
        root GET    /                         users#new
users_create GET    /users/create(.:format)   users#create
 users_login GET    /users/login(.:format)    users#login
```

Comment: post the result of `rake routes` command

Comment: @RSB Added it now as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was:

I needed to remove `resources :users` from the `routes.rb` file.

Everything is working as expected now. After doing a little bit of research it seems that the problem with having `resources :users` in there is that when browsers try to access the page they try to perform a command by using an HTTP method, which is either `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, or `PATCH`.

When the page looks for an incoming command which in this case was `GET /users/login`, it tries to map it to a controller action. If the first matching route is `resources :users`, it will send it to the `show` action.

It seems that this is due to the default CRUD system Rails uses where each HTTP method represents a CRUD action (correct me if I am wrong):

```
GET is show
POST is create
DELETE is destroy
PATCH is update
```

I got most of this research from [Rails Routing from the Outside In, Section 2.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Don't confuse the HTTP verb with a specific CRUD action (not always). Sure, DELETE is destroy, POST is generally create but is often used for more than 'simple' creation, PUT/PATCH is update, but poor old GET is just about anything - the index view is a response to a GET, show is a response to a GET, anything can be a response to a GET as long as that action is idempotent (doesn't change anything server-side).

Comment: @railsdog I think perhaps because my `view/users` folder was lacking an `index.html.erb` file, that it may have mapped the `GET` request to `show`, but I can't be certain (well, I did say "correct me if I'm wrong"!). I am actually reading up now to see why exactly it may have been `GET` mapping to `show`. I'll post my findings later for everyone.

Comment: Routing works based on a combination of HTTP method and pattern matching of the URL. With the resources :users in your routes.rb

GET  users/1  and
GET users/login

will both match the first route in the routing that is a GET method, and looks like "users/something". As far as routing is concerned, '1' can be that 'something', and 'login' can be that 'something', and the first route that matched, is the show.

What happens if you place the resources :users AFTER your custom routes? IIRC, in that case, your users/login will match only users/login, and users/1 should match the show route.